How to charge the image of link
I have a question, is it possible to put the image of a url in this code, instead of the one in android:background=@drawnings/banner_icon another one that is hosted in a url??. Thanks everyone
The code:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_logo"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/banner_icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_logo_url"
    android:background="@url("http://host.ddns.net")" 
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/placeholder_image" />



You cannot do that in an XML layout as you have it. However, there are a variety of image loading libraries, such as Coil, that you can use from your Kotlin code to load an image from a URL into an ImageView.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

It's possible but you need to create a custom ImageView class & define your custom attribute. After that, you can load image from java / kotlin file using 3rd party libraries like "picasso - Image Loader". It will allow you to define URL directly into XML file without writing anything in your activity to load image dynamically. & You can reuse it in multiple activities / classes,
